# Refer to a specific page of a multipage object

Tags: cross-referencing

I am sure the answer to this exists somewhere here, but I am just not able to find it. I have many multipage figures/tables etc. in my document. I would like to be able to refer to a specific page of a multipage object. Using `~\pageref{somelabel}`, I am able to refer to the first page of the object. If I know that my reference of interest is say, on the 5th page, how do I get `~\pageref{somelabel}` to link to the 5th page of this multipage object. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you only want the number or also a working hyperlink which jumps to this page? The first can be done by extracting the page number of the first page and adding 4.

Comment: it depends a bit _how_ you are getting multipage tables and figures, as by default LaTeX does not support either. But basically for example with longtable you should be able to go \label{here} at an arbitrary cell in the table and access \pagref{here} as usual, and should get the page number that that row lands on.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I would like it to be a working hyperlink. @DavidCarlisle, that is an excellent tip, thanks! I have many longtables. I also have multipage figures. They are basically many plots that are included in the document (as one figure) via the `~\pdfpages` option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a mock-up of how you could go about obtaining your hyper-linked page references.

Assume the following is your multi-page image (or table):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

This creates a 10-page document containing "stuff." Now you can include this in your main document in the following hypothetical way using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\newcounter{myimage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
See page~\pageref{myimage-5} for more details.
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\stepcounter{myimage}\label{myimage-\themyimage}}]{lipsum50}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

The above creates a 12-page document with the 10-page image on pages 2-11. Page X receives the label `myimage-X` via `pagecommand`. `pagecommand` steps some counter (`myimage`) and also inserts a unique label. Then you can refer to the specific page of a multi-page image using `\pageref{myimage-<page>}` like in my example:

[image]

`\pageref{myimage-5}` refers to page 6. For multiple multi-page images/tables, you need to reset the counter before each inclusion (`\setcounter{myimage}{0}`) and also provide a unique label for each image/table. The latter requirement is usually the default when working with labels, so shouldn't influence your workflow.

The above discussion involves the inclusion of multi-page "images." Using multi-page tables in the [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) sense you can insert `\label` inside the table where you want to obtain the exact reference you need for the page it's on.

Comment: +1 I'm doing it almost identical in my thesis, but for a different reason.